# How to set navigationOptions on stateless component with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react component like

```
const Example = () => (<View>...</View>);
```

Using react-navigation I would normally apply navigation options by saying

```
Example.navigationOptions = { options };
```

With typescript I am getting the error

`[ts] Property 'navigationOptions' does not exist on type '(props: Props) => Element'.`

How can I fix this?

I tried writing an interface

```
interface ExampleWithNavigationOptions extends Element {
    navigationOptions?;
}
```

But with no luck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key idea is to specify correct type for `Example` constant. Probably, `react-navigation` already provides that type. But, you can also extend build-in `React` interface smth like this:

```
    interface NavStatelessComponent extends React.StatelessComponent {
        navigationOptions?: Object
    }

    const Example: NavStatelessComponent = () => {
        return (
            <View>
               ...
            </View>
        )
    }

    Example.navigationOptions = {
        /*
        ...
        */
    }

    Example.propTypes = {
        /*
        ...
        */
    }
```

Comment: whats the points of defining navigationOptions as object ... The point of types are to know what this is for

Comment: This is not a good answer. It suggests you to create an own type which is not required. Please check Sat Mandir Khalsa's answer for a proper way to do this.

Comment: many bad practices here, and there is no need to use return you can return `() => (<View....)`

Comment: This is not a valid answer. Typescript is used for working with types not bypassing or hacking your way around them. I'm surprised so many people have upvoted this answer. And it was even accepted.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the following:

```
import {
  NavigationScreenProps,
  NavigationScreenComponent
} from 'react-navigation'

interface Props extends NavigationScreenProps {
  // ... other props
}

const MyScreen: NavigationScreenComponent<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {
  // ... your component
}

MyScreen.navigationOptions = {
  // ... your navigation options
}

export default MyScreen
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted one is a flailing hack to fight with TypeScript not embrace it's sweetness.

Comment: If you want auto-complete while you type the `navigationOptions`, you can cast the navigation options object as `NavigationScreenOptions` which can be imported from `react-navigation` (i.e `MyScreen.navigationOptions = {} as NavigationScreenOptions`)

Comment: The best answer, your interface will inherit the navigations types for the stateless, https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/ace2cd0c6c6faa8957ff3fe633d843ee7524db4a/typescript/react-navigation.d.ts#L227

Comment: `NavigationScreenProps` no longer seems to be around. This worked for me: `NavigationScreenComponent<
  OwnProps,
  NavigationBottomTabScreenComponent
>`

Answer (score 10):

For `react-navigation` v4, where you have `react-navigation-tabs` and `react-navigation-stack` as separate libraries, you need to do something similar to [Sat Mandir Khalsa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55171256/4033215), but you just need to use the correct types from the correct library. For example, if it is a screen from `createStackNavigator`, you need to do:

```
import {
  NavigationStackScreenComponent,
  NavigationStackScreenProps
} from 'react-navigation-stack'

interface Props extends NavigationStackScreenProps {
  // your props...
}

export const HomeScreen: NavigationStackScreenComponent<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  // your options...
}
```

Likewise, the `react-navigation-tabs` library has types like `NavigationBottomTabScreenComponent` and `NavigationTabScreenProps` that you can use instead.

Answer (score 2):

If the case is that you want the same navigation option for all your components, remember you can set the `defaultNavigationOptions` in the `createStackNavigator`. Here is the [React Navigation API](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig) if you need an example.