# How to declare navigationOptions for functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to set navigationOptions for a  functional component. Every example shows only class components. How can I set navigationOptions?

Edit 1:
Someone suggested me this solution

```
function YourComponent() {
  return <Text>Hi</Text>
}

YourComponent.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Your custom label...',
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set navigationOptions on stateless component with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117173/how-to-set-navigationoptions-on-stateless-component-with-typescript)