# react navigation: how to pass redux props with NavigationStackScreenComponent type in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I started using typescript in my react native project (typescript newbie) and hit a problem with navigationOptions in functional component with typescript, i solved it thanks to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117173/how-to-set-navigationoptions-on-stateless-component-with-typescript) however when i try to pass redux props its telling me

```
Property 'authType' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<NavigationStackScreenProps<Params, Props>>
```

this is my code

```
interface Props {
 authType: string;
}

interface Params {
 routeName: string;
}

const Customer: NavigationStackScreenComponent<Params, Props> = ({
 navigation,
 authType,
 }) => {
 .... Component
 }

 Customer.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
   title: navigation.getParam('routeName'),
 });
```

I think this means that the prop i am passing is not being read  although i am passing it.

I used NavigationStackScreenComponent in order to be able to use

```
Customer.navigationOptions etc
```

otherwise its gonna tell me

```
ts] Property 'navigationOptions' does not exist
```

I am really beggining to love typescript , Any idea how to use authType Props without it screaming at me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like

```js
interface Props {
 authType: string;
}

type CustomerType = React.ComponentType<Props & NavigationStackScreenProps> & { navigationOptions: NavigationStackOptions | ((props: NavigationStackScreenProps) => NavigationStackOptions) }

const Customer: CustomerType = ({
 navigation,
 authType,
}) => {
 .... Component
}
```

Comment: It works but we are back to square one
tells me 
`Property 'navigationOptions' does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent<Props & NavigationStackScreenProps<Params, unknown>>'
`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

```
type Params = {
  routeName: string;
};

type Props = {
  authType?: string;
  navigation: NavigationStackProp;
};

const Customer: NavigationStackScreenComponent<Params> = ({
  authType,
  navigation,
}: Props) => {
```

I just made the passing props optional.